# How to create a view with two special tables (right side with 2 foreign keys and left side with one unique key)

Tags: sql-server-2008, view, left-join

I have two tables named `FPS_FORMCONTENT` and `FPS_TEAM` declared like this:

```
   FPS_FORMCONTENT       FPS_TEAM
   *****************    ************
   * ContentID     *    * TeamID   *
   * HostTeamID    *    * TeamName *
   * GuestTeamID   *    ************
   *****************
```

`HostTeamID` and `GuestTeamID` are both foreign keys and their value comes from `FPS_TEAM` (`ID`).

How can I join these two tables in such a way that I can get `HostTeam` name and `GuestTeam` name from `FPS_TEAM` in only one row?

If `FPS_FORMCONTENT` contains these values :

```
********************************************
* ContentID *   HostTeamID   *  GuestTeamID*
********************************************
*    1      *      2         *      3      *
********************************************
```

and `FPS_TEAM` contains these values :

```
********************************
* TeamID  *  TeamName          *
********************************
*  2      *  FC Barcelona      *
*  3      *  Real Madrid       *
********************************
```

Result after joining must be :

```
    * ContentID     TeamName(HostTeamName)      TeamName(GuestTeamName)
    ********************************************************************
    *    1              FC Barcelona                 Real Madrid
    ********************************************************************
```

I can not get the above result using `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT JOIN`, `RIGHT JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`,...

Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT
    t1.ContentID,
    t1.HostTeamID,
    HomeTeamName = HomeTeam.TeamName,
    t1.GuestTeamID,
    GuestTeamName = GuestTeam.TeamName
FROM 
    dbo.FPS_FORMCONTENT t1
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.FPS_TEAM HomeTeam ON t1.HostTeamID = HomeTeam.TeamID   
INNER JOIN
    dbo.FPS_TEAM GuestTeam ON t1.GuestTeamID = GuestTeam.TeamID
```

Assuming that an entry in `FPS_FORMCONTENT` always **must have** both a `HostTeamID` and a `GuestTeamID` (after all - a match only makes sense if you have **two teams**), then there's no need for an outer join - those values **must be present** and they must have a corresponding value in `FPS_TEAM` - so an `INNER JOIN` will be perfect for this case.

And since you want to get both the home team's name, as well as the guest team's name, you just need to do **two JOINs** to the `FPS_TEAM` table. That's really all there is to it!